# Idris - Type errors in dependently typed functions

Tags: functional-programming, idris, dependent-type

I'm having a problem with unexpected type errors in Idris when I try to use my dependently-typed functions in the REPL. Here's what I have:

```
data Expr : Type -> Type where
  Null     : Expr ()
  Lift     : Show a => a -> Expr a
  Add      : Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Mul      : Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a

data Context : Type where
  Root  : Context
  Error : String -> Context
  L     : Expr a -> Context -> Expr b -> Expr c -> Context
  R     : Expr a -> Context -> Expr b -> Expr c -> Context
  M     : Expr a -> Context -> Expr b -> Expr c -> Context

data Zipper : Type -> Type where
  Z : Expr a -> Context -> Zipper a
  E : String -> Context -> Zipper String

UnZip : Zipper b -> Type
UnZip (Z {a} e c) = Expr a
UnZip (E x c)     = String

unZip : (x : Zipper a) -> UnZip x
unZip (Z e c) = e
unZip (E x c) = x

total
ZipRight : Zipper a -> Type
ZipRight (Z (Add {a} l r) c)            = Zipper a
ZipRight (Z (Mul {a} l r) c)            = Zipper a
ZipRight _                              = Zipper String

err : String
err = "Some Error"

total
right : (x : Zipper a) -> ZipRight x
right (Z Null c)                     = E err c
right (Z (Lift _) c)                 = E err c
right (Z (Add l r) c)                = Z r (R (Add l r) c Null l)
right (Z (Mul l r) c)                = Z r (R (Mul l r) c Null l)
```

when I go to run the following in the REPL
`unZip $ right $ Z (Add (Lift 2) (Mul (Lift 3) (Lift 4))) Root` I get the expected `Expr Integer`.

when I add an additional `right` to the line in
`unZip $ right $ right $ Z (Add (Lift 2) (Mul (Lift 3) (Lift 4))) Root` I get a type error between `ZipRight (right (Z (Add (Lift 2) (Sub (Lift 4) (Lift 5))) Root)) (Type of right (right (Z (Add (Lift 2) (Sub (Lift 4) (Lift 5))) Root)))` and `Zipper a (Expected Type)`

however running `right $ right $ Z (Add (Lift 2) (Mul (Lift 3) (Lift 4))) Root` shows the expected `Zipper Integer`.

What I would like to know is. Why am I getting a type error with the 2nd call to `right` and is there a way I can fix my code so that either, the error will no longer occur, or that I can refactor in such a way that the problem is circumvented?

Kind regards,

Donovan

Comment: It's almost like the 2nd call to right happens -before- the ZipRight type-level function gets evaluated. If this is what's happening, does anyone out there know a way of fixing it?

Comment: Making right total results in functioning code.

Comment: Ugh, so it does! Would you like to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'd rather someone else come tell us both _why_ the original error occurs.  Glad that helped though!

Comment: I don't know what's going on exactly, but I suspect that the problem may be that the typechecker is shy about evaluating programs which have not been checked total.

Comment: I'd say it's good practice to start an Idris module with `%default total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the function total fixes the problem.
As to *why* the problem occurs in the first place, I'm still in the dark!